# Operating System not found and can't get in into bios

Tags: operating-systems

I have a problem installing OS on my laptop.

I tried to install windows 10 OS in my laptop, during the process I deleted the old OS and when I tried to install the new one, the computer found out that there is wrong in my bootable drive so I boot it again and when I insert it into my laptop, I can't get in in the bios, it always say "Operating System not found" I tried to press different keys but I still can't get into the bios. I used ACER laptop.

Can anyone help me of what should I do?

Comment: You need to get into the BIOS as you suspect.   What model Acer? If you are getting an "Operatng System Not Found" its attempting to boot from a non-bootable disk.

Comment: I use ACER Model no. MS2380

Comment: try to solve one problem at a time, first getting into the BIOS . And why don't you try googling how to get into the BIOS for your model of laptop  after having  just pressed dfferent keys and not got in.  I did find something on "Acer Travel Mate P245(MS2380) "  but not about getting into the BIOS, and I found another thing on the Acer Travel Mate P245 (not mentioning MS2380), and it said F2
"

Comment: You can also mentioin what keys you tried.. and include a screenshot etc.

Comment: I tried esc, del, fn+f2, f12 even f1, f10 and f8 @barlop

Comment: @GelSSy  what about just F2?  And try each of them but hammering the key like a maniac  Like a mad woodpecker so like in 5 seconds a key would be tapped 35+ times and don't waste a moment so as soon as the computer restarts/starts go nuts hammering. (not hard but fast)

Comment: @barlop i also tried f2, but the only key that will beep is f12, it will beep once i pressed it but it will go back again to the error message.

Comment: @GelSSy Try a question that gives your make and model of laptop, maybe on hardware.stackexchange, and ask how to get into the BIOS/UEFI and explain your struggles.  Operating system is irrelevant don't even mention it for that question. Also try https://community.acer.com/en/categories/en    acer's looks like a rubbishly organised forum, like hardly any sectoins, but is worth a try

Comment: @GelSSy Acer have AMAZING support services, at least in terms of access.  look here https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/service-contact  even a telephone number 24/7  Call them and ask  And if they don't know then try lve chat and if they don't know then Email them.  Besides the Acer forum too. And don't ask anything about OS. Forget the OS. You are asking Acer only about Acer specifc things that they are an expert on. That is, getting into the BIOS/UEFI

Comment: @barlop Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that, by deleting your OS, you're implying that you reformatted your hard drive and it's completely erased.

I'm also presuming that you're trying to install W10 from your DVD drive.

The Acer is looking to boot up the OS from the hard drive. That's the problem. You need to change it to boot from the DVD drive.

You need to get into BIOS and change the booting priority to the DVD drive. To get there, turn on the computer and press one of the function keys, not sure your model, mine was F10, before it looks on the hard drive and says "Operating System not found".

From there, it should load a simple interface and there should be sub menu where you can change the booting priority, good luck.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and provide more specific instructions for the author to follow?

Comment: Yes, I reformatted the drive and completely erased and yes I was trying to install W10. The thing is I cant get into the bios, I tried many keys, but the f12 seems different because it will beep once I pressed it but still it will go back to the error message.

Comment: AT Ramhound.  Perhaps you can be more specific about what specific instructions you think he should include. And He might not have those specific instructions that you think he should include.  Bear in mind that the OP can't access his BIOS, and the answerer doesn't have the same laptop as the OP so won't know the idiosyncracies of accessing the BIOS on that laptop in order to help the OP get in when the OP is struggling. So he may know no better(or worse) than you how to get into the BIOS/"BIOS" or UEFI.